# Add and subtract values group by Unique ID

Tags: awk, sed

I have records like this: I have to add/subtract the values of columns 2 and 4 if there is add and subtract if it is DEL.

```
12345)63)ADD)3
12345)40)ADD)2
12345)40)ADD)2
12345)40)DEL)2
67892)30)ADD)5
67892)-20)ADD)3
```

Output should be:

```
12345|103|5|108
67892|10|8|18
```

1. column 1 - unique ID
2. column 2 - adding column A
3. column 3 - adding column B
4. column 4 - Count A + count B

Comment: What have you tried and what problem did you encounter that you need help with?

Comment: please consider accepting the answer instead of thanking; also explanation of how that output produced is really bad, I just had realized by myself how it's turned into that output after several times looking input/output.

Answer (score 2):

One way using the **awk** utility is as shown:

```
awk -F ')' -v OFS='|' '
prev != $1 {
  if (NR > 1) {
    dump(prev, s[2], s[4])
  }
  s[2] = s[4] = 0
  prev = $1
}
{
  mult = $3 == "ADD" ? 1 : -1
  for (i in s) s[i] += mult * $(i)
}
END {
  dump(prev, s[2], s[4])
}
function dump(p,a,b,  t) {
  t = a+b
  print p, a, b, t 
}
' file
```

**output:**

```
12345|103|5|108
67892|10|8|18
```